Calculation of compound percentage - inaccurate result with specific input data
I am creating a function that calculates the compound percentage. It is enhanced by adding periodic deposits and tracking the results month by month.
Everything works fine, but when I set the capitalization to monthly and the deposits to annual, the result is inaccurate.
How do I know that inaccurate? My reference source is OmniCalculator - https://www.omnicalculator.com/finance/compound-interest. In my case, the totalProfit variable is different from the result in OmniCalculator.
Example input data (works fine):
amount: 10000,
periods: 30,
periodsType: 12, (1 - months, 12 - years)
interestRate: 8,
capitalisation: 12, (1 - monthly, 3 - quarterly, 12 - yearly)
regularPaymentAmount: 500,
regularPaymentFrequency: 12 (1 - monthly, 3 - quarterly, 12 - yearly)

Function call: percent(10000, 30, 12, 8, 12, 500, 12)
Example input data (works inaccurately)
amount: 10000,
periods: 30,
periodsType: 12,
interestRate: 8,
capitalisation: 1,
regularPaymentAmount: 500,
regularPaymentFrequency: 12

Function call: percent(10000, 30, 12, 8, 1, 500, 12)
With these (inaccurate) inputs, my profit is 144 610,47, and OmniCalculator's is 149 179,31.
Do any of you know how to improve the accuracy of this function so that its result is accurate?


function percent(
    amount,
    periods,
    periodsType,
    interestRate,
    capitalisation,
    regularPaymentAmount = 0,
    regularPaymentFrequency,
    whenPayment = "before"
) {
    amount = parseFloat(amount);
    periods = parseFloat(periods);
    periodsType = parseFloat(periodsType);
    interestRate = parseFloat(interestRate);
    capitalisation = parseInt(capitalisation);
    regularPaymentAmount = parseFloat(regularPaymentAmount);
    regularPaymentFrequency = parseInt(regularPaymentFrequency);

    let breakdowns = [];
    let capital = amount;
    let totalPayment = 0;
    let prevCapital = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i <= periods * periodsType; i++) {
        if (i % periodsType === 1) {
            prevCapital = capital;
        }

        //payment BEFORE
        if (
            regularPaymentAmount !== 0 &&
            whenPayment === "before" &&
            i % regularPaymentFrequency === 0
        ) {
            prevCapital += regularPaymentAmount;
            capital += regularPaymentAmount;
            totalPayment += regularPaymentAmount;
        }

        if (i % capitalisation === 0) {
            // gains + intérêts
            capital = capital * (1 + (interestRate / 100) * (capitalisation / 12));
        }

        //payment AFTER
        if (
            regularPaymentAmount !== 0 &&
            whenPayment === "after" &&
            i % regularPaymentFrequency === 0
        ) {
            prevCapital += regularPaymentAmount;
            capital += regularPaymentAmount;
            totalPayment += regularPaymentAmount;
        }

        const snapshotStep = Math.min(regularPaymentFrequency, periodsType, capitalisation);
        if (i % snapshotStep === 0) {
            breakdowns.push({
                lp: i,
                amount: capital,
                regularPaymentAmount: i % regularPaymentFrequency === 0 ? regularPaymentAmount : 0,
                profit: capital - (totalPayment + amount),
            });
        }
    }

    let totalAdditionalPayments = totalPayment + amount;
    let totalProfit = capital - amount - totalPayment;
    return totalProfit;
}
console.log(percent(10000, 30, 12, 8, 1, 500, 12))




What steps have you taken to debug this?

I tried to divide the payment equally for each month, instead of posting it all at once. I also checked whether placing it after capitalization is a solution. I spent several hours experimenting, mostly blindly, but nothing helped.
I also looked at the source of the page, where I found the code used for the calculation, but it is extremely complicated and, imo, simply unintuitive. You can find it in the folder www.omnicalculator.com -> finance -> compound-interest in devtools

I would work through it by hand, and compare the output of each step.

Maybe you can advise me on how I should go about it? Is there any order of operations for such a process?

I'm sure there is, but I don't know what that order would be. This seems to be more of an algorithm issue than a javascript issue. I would research how to calculate compound percentage to determine the order of operations. Calculate it by hand and compare it step by step with your function.

After several hours of hard work, I was able to customize the function to fit my needs and ecosystem. I studied 1000 lines of code to finally achieve my goal. I had a great time doing it. It was like a puzzle. Thank you for motivating me to move forward!
